# Binary operation & its output as input in another one

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Exercise A question 6 from A BOOK OF ABSTRACT ALGEBRA by Charles C
>   Pinter:
>
> Binary operation *: $A\times A\to A$ is defined in the following way:
>   $(a,b)\mapsto a*b$

I want to determine with explanation if the rule below is an operation

$a * b = |a - b|$ on $\mathbb N_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2$ main conditions required to be met to show that a given rule is an "operation" as you've defined:

1. For any specific ordered pair $(a,b)$ used as input, the operation always gives just one value, i.e., it never gives $2$ or more values.
2. The resulting value of the rule is always an element within the set $A$.

For the particular rule

$$a * b = |a - b| \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

on the set  $\{n ∈ \mathbb Z: n \ge 0\} $, first note that $|a-b| = a - b$ if $a \ge b$ and $|a - b| = b - a$ otherwise. Thus, it always gives just one value, so the first condition is satisfied.

Next, note with $a$ and $b$ being integers, then $|a - b| \ge 0$ and is also an integer. Thus, the result is an element of the set $A$, so the second condition is also satisfied.

In summary, the stated rule is an operation.

Comment: 1 * 3 = 2 and 3 * 1 = 2. The two operations all point to the same value. Does it still qualify as an operation ?

Comment: @EALeben There is no such additional property required by your definition of an operation, so yes.  If such a property is met, e.g. $a * b = b* a$, then this is called *commutativity*, but a commutative operation is still an operation.

Comment: @EALeben Note the definition does not state that the results must be to *distinct* elements. If it did require this, then the rule would be considered to be "injective", such as described in Wikipedia's [Injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) article.

Comment: @heropup, could we rephrase the question and consider the given operation '*' symmetric relation?